# Why does the simulator always start in Landscape mode on Xcode4?

Tags: xcode4, ios-simulator, simulator

I just installed Xcode4 on my machine, setting up a new project.

When I run the simulator, the iphone always appears in Landscape mode. Anyone knows where I find the magic setting to run it in portrait so my head doesn't get twisted all the time?

thanks

---

EDIT:

It appears there must be sth in my code that makes the simulator hardware tip to landscape mode since  before and after I test my app it is protrait again ... wierd ...

Not sure where I could have done sth like that to it since I use a new project (tab bar based) and only fiddle around the second VC ...

Also - when rotating the devide, the status bar and content do not change orientation ...

Answer (score 36):

I just had the same problem. But all supported interface orientations were selected in Project - Target - Summary - Supported Device Orientations.

But there is another reason why the simulator starts in landscape mode. The **order of the 'Supported interface orientation' items** of your project-info.plist file is also important. Check if the "Portrait (bottom home button)" is on the very first position in the list. If not, just move it up.

[image: Supported interface orientations]

Comment: I did a clean & rebuild and restarted the simulator before this took effect.  Not sure if both were required.

Comment: Worked fine for me without clean.

Answer (score 6):

This happens when using some of the templates in Xcode 4.  It's easy to change:

- Open yourProject-info.plist file
- In the 'Supported interface orientations' key remove both landscape orientations

[image]

- And add your chosen orientation(s), eg 'Portrait (bottom home button)'

[image]

- You can also make these changes in your Project - Target - Summary - Supported Device Orientation.  Press the portrait button and depress the rest. It not very clear but these are buttons; dark grey means its selected, and light grey means its not.

[image]

Later, if your app requires landscape orientation then you can simply add your desired orientations back into the info.plist file.  Remember to return YES for these orientations in the applicable view controller's shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method.

Answer (score 1):

This is temporary solution, you can move your simulator when it comes in landscape mode.

Click on simulator on dock -> Harware -> use rotate left or Right

Comment: I could not find any setting in settings for simulator.all you app runs like this or only one.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.
I found out that on that grey area of Supported Device Orientations (dark grey means selected), you can switch everything off, and reselect the orientation you might want to use according to the order in your mind. so if you want want your simulator always firstly run portrait mode, just switch it on first, and then after that you can switch other buttons on.