# ios - simulator started opening in horizontal view. How to get it to go back to default portrait view?

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a strange thing that recently happened. The simulator keeps starting in horizontal view. Is there a setting to make it start in portrait view? I keep digging around for that setting but can't seem to locate it.

Thanks and sorry for such a simple question.

Comment: Yes there is. If you go to your project in Xcode where you have "boxes" for your iphone orientation, click them in order from portrait up, portrait down and then landscape up/down. That should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rotating it with CMD + left arrow, that might do the trick.

Comment: I am able to rotate it once without problems. The issue was to make the emulator start in portrait view as a default.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the 'Supported interface orientation' items of your project-info.plist file is key.

Check if the "Portrait (bottom home button)" is on the very first position in the list. If not, just move it up.

(from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531125/why-does-the-simulator-always-start-in-landscape-mode-on-xcode4))

Comment: just checked and my portrait view is the default. But nice idea!